# Concentration on a spell while casting a spell with a longer casting time

Tags: spells, spellcasting, concentration

Is casting a spell with a casting time longer than 1 action considered “concentrating” on it, for the purpose of keeping concentration on a different spell already cast?

Ex.: *Flaming sphere* on the field, next round starting to cast *conjure minor elemental* (1min).
Does the *flaming sphere* puff at the start of the minute or at the end, when the spell slot is spent and the spell’s effect takes place?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. What RPG and edition are you asking about? Please indicate this by editing the corresponding tag (e.g. [dnd-5e]) into your post. Once you do that, your post can be reapproved and answered (or we can direct you to where your question has already been answered).